# Receiving Gestures In an AVPlayer's Parent View

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avplayer, uitapgesturerecognizer

The long version: I am writing an app for `iOS 8` in `Swift`, and its main functionality requires it to **display a slideshow of sorts of pictures and videos**. Considering that, to my knowledge, an `AVPlayer` cannot display pictures (I've tried feeding it an image URL in the same way I've fed it a video URL, and no luck), this requires me to add and remove a `UIImageView` or an `AVPlayer` from the view in order to display the appropriate content. However, in order to show the content correctly, I have to hide the app's `navigationbar` by default. The idea is to show it again if the user taps on the view. The view has a `TapGestureRecognizer` that serves this purpose. These tap gestures work correctly, assuming the view's content is the `imageview`. However, if the view presently contains the `AVPlayer`, the gestures are not received, rendering me unable to allow the user to show the `navigationbar` and leave the view. Here is how the `AVPlayer` is added to the view:

```
if (Utilities.IsVideo(url)) {
            var escapedUrl = url.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: escapedUrl!))
            var cont = AVPlayerViewController()
            cont.player = player
            self.addChildViewController(cont)
            self.view.addSubview(cont.view)
            cont.view.frame = self.view.frame
            player.play()
        }
```

The short version: I have a view in an iOS app that contains a `TapGestureRecognizer`. The taps do not pass through an `AVPlayer` that is added to the view. How do I detect these taps?

It is worthy of mention that if the user taps on one of the media *controls* (such as the play button), the tap gesture is then recognized and its action triggered.